# Check the type of draggable

Tags: jquery

The draggable element below can be an `<li>` element. Can I check if the element dragged is an `<li>` using `.attr` or some other method?

```
$(".myCss" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.draggable.attr('class'));
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$(".myCss" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if (ui.draggable.is("li")) {
            // ...
        }
    } 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZsT2Y/